# Можно ли в if одним знаком сравнивать несколько значений?

Tags: php, if

Назрел такой вопрос. Имеет такая строчка `if($q1 > $q2 && $q1 > $q3 && $q1 > $q4 ...)`. Можно ли ее как-то сократить? И как это можно сделать? Например там `if($q1 > $q2,$q3,$q4)`. Я не могу просто по общим запросам найти информации в интернете.

Comment: Нет, так делать __нельзя__

Comment: @u_mulder, может есть какие-то способы сократить эту строчку?

Comment: Можно воспользоваться математикой и сравнить `q1` с наибольшим элементом из `q2,q3,....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если элемент больше самого большого элемента в наборе, то он больше всех остальных, посему можно написать так:

```
if ($q1 > max([$q2,$q3,$q4,$q5])) {


}
```